# Adding Cubic-bezier to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, yui, transition

Looking for insight or help on the use of yahoo apis: 'yui transitions'.

I'm trying to add a cubic bezier to the 3 cards on SimplyPrepaidDealer.com using jQuery preferably but am I stuck using 'yui' to activate the code snippet?

Recently a [site](http://www.simplyprepaiddealer.com) was built using yui 'yahooapis' as the rel stylesheet.

Yui uses its own transitions. http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/transition/

The site was built using a lot of jQuery, CSS, yui-pure.  Where can I fit a code snippet to add a cubic-bezier transition onto the containers that open on the site i.e. prepaid, market, story.

```
    CSS Code snippets, short and long-hand:

   -webkit-transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); 
   -moz-transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); 
   -o-transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); 
    transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); /* custom */

   -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); 
   -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); 
   -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); 
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.205, 0.725, 0.460, 1.000); /* custom */
```